# Find v3 so that v1 v2 v3 is a basis of R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

> Let $v_1=(2,3,4),v_2=(1,0,2)$.
>   Find $v_3$ so that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I don't really know how to solve and it's a common question, I would really appreciate the help.
Thank you.

Comment: I see that someone has downvoted this question, but not commented on how it might be improved. Please comment on how the question can be improved when possible.

Comment: @Galen I did not downvote, but it is a common problem with questions on the site that the authors do not provide any context where the question arises from, nor their effort of trying to approach the problem.

Comment: I recommend feedback as it helps questioners understand why their question is not well-received. For extremely common issues, they can be referred to the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) or its child pages.

Comment: @gt6989b why would I ask a question if I knew how to solve it, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RouaSabbagh It's one thing to not know how to approach something. A very different thing is not to try *anything*

Comment: I really appreciate the help but I tried solving the question and I didn't know how to so I thought that someone might help me so I asked, it's really not that big of a deal.

Comment: @RouaSabbagh Like I wrote, I did not downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You need a third vector which is linearly independent of the first two. The easiest way in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is to take
$$
v_1 \times v_2
$$
which is perpendicular to both $v_1$ and $v_2$ and hence linearly independent of both.

Comment: Thank you so much, so just to be sure I have to take the cross product right then check that it is linearly independent

Comment: @RouaSabbagh it should be perpendicular to both vectors if you did the arithmetic correctly

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: @RouaSabbagh you are welcome, glad to help you. I hope you stay around and contribute to the site.